# Can't accees to redux store (basic redux example)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I saw http://blog.tylerbuchea.com/super-simple-react-redux-application-example/  this page with example and tried repeat it :

```
          import React from 'react';
            import ReactDom from 'React-dom';
            import {Redux,bindActionCreators,combineReducers,
    createStore,applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
            import { connect, Provider} from 'react-redux';
            import thunk from 'redux-thunk';


            // actions.js
             const activateGeod = geod => ({
                type: 'ACTIVATE_GEOD',
                geod,
            });

             const closeGeod = () => ({
                type: 'CLOSE_GEOD',
            });

            // reducers.js
            const geod = (state = {}, action) => {
                switch (action.type) {
                    case 'ACTIVATE_GEOD':
                        return action.geod;
                    case 'CLOSE_GEOD':
                        return {};
                    default:
                        return state;
                }
            };

             const reducers = combineReducers({
                geod,
            });


const customMiddleWare = store => next => action => {
    console.log("Middleware triggered:", action);
    next(action);
};



function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
    const store = createStore(
        reducers,
        initialState,
        //applyMiddleware(thunk)
        applyMiddleware(customMiddleWare)
    )
    return store;
};

            const store = configureStore();

            store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()))


            // App.js
             class App extends React.Component {

                render() {
                    debugger
                    return (
                        <div>
                            PAGE:

                            <h1>{this.props.geod.title || 'Hello World!'}</h1>

                            {this.props.geod.title ?
                                <button onClick={this.props.closeGeod}>
                                    Exit Geod
                                </button> :
                                <button onClick={() => 
        this.props.activateGeod({ title: 'I am a geo dude!' })}>
                                    Click Me!
                                </button>
                            }



                        </div>
                    );
                }

            }

            // AppContainer.js
            const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
                geod: state.geod,
            });

            const mapDispatchToProps = {
                activateGeod,
                closeGeod,
            };

            const AppContainer = connect(
                mapStateToProps,
                mapDispatchToProps
            )(App);



            ReactDom.render(

                <Provider store={store}>
                    <App />
                </Provider>,
                document.getElementById('wr')
                    );
```

but I got error :

> Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

It's possible set defaults props for state.props?

Comment: where do you set value for `geod` in your store ?

Comment: I hope since `geod` is not set in your `mapStateToProps`, `geod` is returned as `undefined` and so you get undefined error in your `render`

Comment: const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
 geod: state.geod || {},
});  but error still here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your `this.props.geod` is undefined because you are not rendering connected component. You have connected your app component with redux store like

```
const AppContainer = connect(
            mapStateToProps,
            mapDispatchToProps
        )(App);
```

So your connected component is stored in `AppContainer` but you are rendering `App` like this

```
    ReactDom.render(
       <Provider store={store}>
         <App />
       </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('wr')
   );
```

Where `App` is not connected to store. So solution is to render connected component like this

```
    ReactDom.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer />
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('wr')
   );
```

Comment: thank you so much, I happy when I have simple exaple in redux and can improve it